# export a pdf file from powerpoint with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, pdf-extraction

I want to be able to export the PDF files that I insert in my powerpoint presentation using vba.

I know that you can add .zip extension to the pptx file (just modifying the name of the file) and then check the content of the presentation. It works me to export videos because the videos were stored with the same format but in this case, the pdf files are stored with .bin extension and I cannot do anything with that type of file. Even if I change the extension to .pdf adobe reader is not able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

To PowerPoint, an embedded object is just a static picture of what it's supposed to look like, some data it doesn't have ANY idea what to do with, and some information about the app that created the data.  When you doubleclick the object (or activate it programmatically) it tries to launch the app that created the data and load the data into it.

To do anything with the data beyond activating it from PPT, you'll need to automate the app that opens when you activate the data.

In the case of PDFs, that might be Reader, Acrobat or some other third-party app.